# How to loop the dialogue box in java script?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I have been learning javascript for the past month and today we had loops.
We have a task which I just can't solve properly and I simply can't see what i do wrong.
Task is:

> Make a program that displays a confirm dialog box with the text "Do
> you want to continue?" again and again until the user clicks the
> Cancel button in the dialog box. If the user clicks the OK button in
> the dialog box, then the program shows an alert dialog box with the
> text "Hello!". After the user has closed the alert dialog box the
> program shows the confirm dialog box again.

So far the best solution I could come up with is:

```
confirm("Do you want to continue?")
alert("Hello!")
while(confirm !== true){
    confirm;
}
```

Problem is that confirm box loops but loop goes to alert box no matter the button you press. And I just simply don't get how you make the loop begin again when pressing "ok" on alert box.

Thank you in advance for the advice!

Comment: You're not storing the *result* of `confirm()` anywhere.  The loop is checking if *the `confirm` function itself* doesn't equal `true`, which will always be the case.  And the loop body doesn't do anything.

Comment: `while (confirm("Do you want to continue?")) { alert("Hello!") }`

Answer (score 1):

The `window.confirm` function [returns the result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) of the confirmation (`true` or `false`), but your code isn't capturing that result.  You can capture it in a variable:

```
let confirmed = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
```

Also, take a look at what you're doing here:

```
while(confirm !== true)
```

We already know that `confirm` is *a function*.  And we know that you append parentheses when you want to *call* a function.  So this isn't calling the function, it's just referencing it.  And *the function itself* will never equal `true`, so this loop is infinite (and meaningless).

Additionally, this doesn't do anything:

```
confirm;
```

Again, we know what `confirm` is already and we know how to call a function already.  So this doesn't call the function, it's just a reference to the function.  Sitting there.  Not doing anything.

---

Instead, the loop can check the variable:

```
while (confirmed) {
```

And in the loop you can repeat the call to `confirm` from before the loop:

```
confirmed = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
```

Which leaves us with:

```
let confirmed = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
alert("Hello!");
while (confirmed) {
  confirmed = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
}
```

There's a lot of repetition here.  This can be simplified.  This *also* doesn't do what the assignment asks, because the `alert` operation isn't being repeated.  Let's fix that logic before simplifying:

```
let confirmed = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
while (confirmed) {
  alert("Hello!");
  confirmed = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
}
```

We can remove the duplicate `confirm` operation by simply swapping the operations in the loop, which would make the one outside the loop superfluous:

```
let confirmed = true;
while (confirmed) {
  confirmed = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
  alert("Hello!");
}
```

There's also a lot of repetition of this `confirmed` variable, which we don't really need.  The condition being checked by the loop doesn't need to be a variable, it just needs to evaluate to a boolean value.  And the `confirm` function already returns that.  So just use it directly:

```
while (confirm("Do you want to continue?")) {
  alert("Hello!");
}
```